# How to show $\sum_{d>x,P^+(d)\le y} \mu(d)/d = O (\log{y}\cdot e^{-\log{x}/2\log{y}})$?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I can't see why $$\sum_{d>x,P^+(d)\le y} \mu(d)/d = O (\log{y}\cdot e^{-\log{x}/2\log{y}})\;,$$

where $P^+(d)$ is the greatest prime factor of $d$.

Can anyone give a hint? Thanks.

Comment: What are the ranges for $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $S(x,y)=\left\{ n\leq x:\ P(n)\leq y\right\}$, and let $\psi(x,y)=|S(x,y)|$  be the size of this set. Then, since $|\mu(d)|\leq1$, we may bound your sum above by $\sum_{d>x,\ d\in S(x,y)}\frac{1}{d}.$ Writing this as a Riemann Stieltjes integral, you are looking

$$\sum_{d>x,\ d\in S(x,y)}\frac{1}{d}=\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t}d\left(\psi(t,y)\right)=-\frac{\psi(x,y)}{x}+\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{\psi(t,y)}{t^{2}}dt.$$  Now, the result you desire will follow if you can show that

$$\psi(t,y)\ll te^{-\log t/\log y}.$$

**Remarks:** Usually when talking about the friable/smooth integers, we let $u=\frac{\log x}{\log y}$.  You are trying to prove that $$\psi(x,y)\ll x e^{-u/2}.$$  In fact there are much stronger results than this.  We expect that $\psi(x,y)\asymp x u^{-u}$.  See the [Dickmann De Bruijn rho function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function), or [Hildebrand and Tenenbaum's survey article](http://www.iecn.u-nancy.fr/~tenenb/PUBLIC/PPP/Survey_friables.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!